# How to avoid multiple users creating multiple records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a database with 3 tables. A table called movies, which has 2 values, a unique id I get from themoviedb.org and a title. I also have a table called users which has a name value. My third table is a join table called movies_users, and looks like this,

```
class AddMoviesUsersJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :movies_users, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :movie_id
      t.integer :user_id
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :movies_users
  end
end
```

In my movies.rb model I have

```
has_and_belongs_to_many: users
```

And in my users.rb model I have

```
has_and_belongs_to_many: movies
```

And the create action in my movies_controller.rb looks like this,

```
def create
  respond_with Movie.create(movie_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id))
end
```

A user can do a search action and I will provide them with a list of results I get from themoviedb.org. Themoviedb also provides a unique ID with their movies.

Now when multiple users add the same movie I get multiple records of it. For example I've added the movie Creed with two accounts and this is what my rails console shows,

```
Movie id: 1, title: "Creed",user_id: 1, movie_id: "312221">
Movie id: 2, title: "Creed",user_id: 2, movie_id: "312221">
```

How do I create a relationship between 1 movie and multiple users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I create a relationship between 1 movie and multiple users?

Do this:

```
#app/controllers/movies_controller.rb
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @movie = Movie.find_or_create_by movie_params
      current_user.movies << @movie
   end

   def destroy
      @movie = Movie.find params[:id]
      current_user.movies.destroy @movie #-> only destroys association, not actual object
   end

   private

   def movie_params
      params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :movie_id)
   end
end
```

This will populate `@movie` with a new `Movie` record if one doesn't exist and pull the relevant record if it does. This will allow you to add the `@movie` to the `current_user.movies` hash -- a method described [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many):

[image]

--

As an aside, there's something else you need to be aware of.

You're currently using `user_id` in your `Movie` model. This would suggest a `belongs_to/has_many` relationship - counter to your models.

If you want to just use `has_and_belongs_to_many` in your models, you'll need to remove the `user_id` foreign key from your `movies` table - it doesn't need it.

---

**Update**

```
$ rails c

$ user1 = User.find(1)
$ user1.movies #-> will output movies

$ user2 = User.find(2)
$ user2.movies #-> will output movies
```

Comment: Does the above controller use a relationship model such as `habtm`? Also I've tried to implement your code and while my record is getting saved I'm also getting an post 500 error in my console. `ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template movies/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/alucardu/sites/movieseat/app/views"
  * "/home/alucardu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.5.2/app/views"
):`

Comment: Yes it uses `habtm` (just as you posted in your question). The error comes from a lack of `create.html.erb` in your views. You need to add it or use `redirect_to` in your `create` action

Comment: I've added `redirect_to :root` and indeed the error is gone now. Is there a way to check in the rails console if the relationship is working? Because I've just created 2 different accounts and added the same movie (Creed, like in example in OP). And now when I do Movie.all I see only 1 result, which is good. But I'm wondering if there's a way to see the relationship results somehow.

Comment: This looks great! Thank you for explaining. I do have 1 question left. If one user adds a movie, lets say "Creed". Rails inserts a record into the database with a unique id (starting at 1 for my own database) and a title. If a second user also adds the movie "Creed". How does Rails know the record already exists in my database? What is the defining value here? I hope I explain my question in a understandable way.

Comment: `movie_id`, as you posted in the question. If you need to validate against this, you'll have to provide context on how you retrieve it from the third party API

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95124/discussion-between-peter-boomsma-and-rich-peck).